# Avoid focus on first screen field in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I've add some customized buttonfield follow by some label field. 
When opening the app, the first buttonfield gets focus, but I don't need the focus when opening the screen. How to avoid the focus on opening the screen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use NullField like the code below:

```
NullField field = new NullField();
field.setFocus();
```

This will avoid the focus on any field in the screen